# before FinishedLaunching based on response load viewController

Tags: c#, ios, authentication, xamarin, appdelegate

On FinishedLauching I invoke the getRequest to get authentication value from server.
based on the response data want to load the view controller respectively.

```
   public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options){
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        navigationController = new UINavigationController();
        navigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden (true, true);
        loginViewController = new LoginViewController ();
        detailViewController = new DetailViewController ();


    this.AuthenticationRequest();

    boolenTokenData = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.BoolForKey ("Authentication");
    navigationController.AddChildViewController (loginViewController);

    if (boolenTokenData == true){
        navigationController.AddChildViewController (detailViewController);
    }

    window.RootViewController = navigationController;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}
```

// Services Call Request AuthenticationReqest.

```
  NSUserDefaults prefs = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

public void  AuthenticationRequest(){
    ClientObj.ResponseCompleted += _ResponseData;
    ClientObj.ResponseError += _ErrorData;
    string url = "http://192.12.123.123/Authentication/tokenData.json;
        Obj.GET_Request(url);
}


void _ResponseData(object sender, CommonCode.ResponseEventArgs e){
    this.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
        Console.WriteLine ("Response Data ::{ 0}", e.ResponseData.ToString ());

        if(e.ResponseData.ToString ().Length > 0 ){
        prefs.SetBool (true,"Authentication");
        prefs.Synchronize ();

    });
}

void _ErrorData(object sender, CommonCode.ResponseEventArgs e){
    this.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 
        Console.WriteLine ("Response Error:{ 0}",e.Error.Message.ToString ());
            prefs.SetBool (false,"Authentication");
            prefs.Synchronize ();
    });
}
```

In the above case its loading view controller before the response or Error invoke.
Application need to wait until the responseData or ErrorData get invoked.

Comment: its not the correct way to implement, let the load your rootcontroller and then validate from service anything

Comment: I agree with Retro, checking authentication/authorization is something you should only do once the application has started. FinishedLaunching is the method you use to communicate you have started and thus you haven't started yet until you return true.